# Not progressing from Nuxt loading screen

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

We are using Nuxt.

The `ssr`  and `target`  of the `nuxt.config.js` are set as follows

```
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
}
```

Our site is working almost exactly as expected.
However, when we check our site after checking other tabs in our browser, we are sometimes unable to move on from the loading screen.

What is the cause of this? We have logs in the middleware and on each page and component to investigate, but the logs do not show up on the console and we are unable to determine the cause.

What should we suspect and what should we investigate?

The reproduction rate is not 100%. It may have occurred after a day or so.

[image]

Comment: Mostly the tab is just in a sleeping state. When you come back on it, it may not relaunch itself because of something not being fetched or idk. Still, you cannot provide more details, there is no code and no [repro]. Not sure how we can help here.

Comment: Since this problem is not 100% reproducible we could not make the smallest program that would reproduce it. We want to know under what circumstances this occurs in order to give a smaller example. No matter how many logs we put in, no logs are output at all, so we do not know which part is the cause of the problem.

Comment: `this occurs`, not sure what to say here. We will not be able to guess more than you here.

Comment: So you are unable to determine what is causing the problem with the information we currently have. We have added logs to both asyncData and middleware, but they do not show up. We thought that would indicate something. We think our problem comes before the middleware. Where would that be?

We have already confirmed this, but we have not added processing prior to the middleware. So we don't know why the middleware logs are not outputting. That is why we cannot make a minimal defect reproduction code.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/

Comment: Our problem may be similar to this. We are in the process of translating these as we are not native English speakers.
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6338

Comment: This may have something to do with it too. People seem to be having trouble with it too.
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, our phenomenon seems to be the same problem as theirs.
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6442

If I may reiterate the condition they describe, it occurs when multiple tabs are used in Chirome. These do not seem to have been fixed, perhaps because they are busy supporting Nuxt 3.

We are displaying multiple tabs for debugging purposes, but in reality we are only displaying one tab, so it's probably not a problem.